# Comment appelle-t-on un homme content après qu'il a été très en colère ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

On a un homme très en colère. Par exemple : il a cassé son téléphone pour satisfaire ses émotions. Après avoir cassé son téléphone il est maintenant satisfait.

Comment appelle-t-on cet homme ?
Je veux un seul mot (adjectif).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si c'est l'état que l'on veut caractériser, et non le tempérament de la personne, je dirais aussi « assouvi ». 
Cela traduit précisément la nuance de satisfaction immédiate et sensuelle que vous décrivez...

Answer (score 4):

Retour au calme après une colère :

- calmé : d'usage le plus courant
- apaisé (mais ne signifie pas forcément après une colère).
- [rasséréné](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rass%C3%A9r%C3%A9n%C3%A9/1) : un peu moins courant, de style plus soutenu: action de redevenir serein (mais pas toujours après une colère).

On peut être *apaisé* / *rasséréné* après une *forte inquiétude*.

On est toujours *calmé* après avoir été *non calme=en colère/énervé*.

Answer (score 3):

Un homme *[soupe-au-lait](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/soupe-au-lait.php)* : La colère monte très vite et s'arrête tout aussi vite.

Cette expression est liée au comportement du lait chauffé à une certaine température qui se met à déborder très vite, mais, dès que l'on coupe le feu sous la casserole, toute l'écume, toute la mousse, retombe aussitôt.

Être *soupe-au-lait* signifie aussi qu'il n'y a pas de rancune profonde, seulement une surréaction. Une fois que la colère atteint son paroxysme, elle retourne très vite dans l'oubli ; elle ne laisse pas de trace, dénoue les tensions exacerbées et donc amène un calme relatif ensuite.

S'il s'agit de connaître seulement l'état de cette personne après son état colérique, cet homme *satisfait* est souvent *content* (de lui), s'est *calmé*. Ces trois états ne sont pas liés à la colère, mais à un état où les tensions ont réussi à se relâcher.

Pour savoir si cela convient à votre question la traduction *[inverse](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/soupe+au+lait)*.

---

***Complément*** suite aux commentaires

Le Robert donne *capricieux, fantasque, versatile* comme synonyme de *lunatique*.
La colère est les fruits d’une impulsion, elle est instantanée, explosive, arrive immédiatement à son paroxysme, yang, verticale, solaire, tout le contraire des réactions lunatiques, qui varient au rythme de la lune : des réactions indolentes, lentes, qui peuvent être arrêtées ou varier, changeantes au rythme des heures ou des jours : « Tu es bien luné aujourd’hui ? »

Dès qu’Autolycos, le grand-père d’Ulysse, prend le nouveau né sur ses genoux, il se met à crier et vagir furieusement. En le rendant rapidement à sa mère, Anticlée, il dit : « Tu l’appelleras Ulysse », ce qui signifie “l’homme en colère”.

… mais si l’on appelle quelqu’un d’“Ulysse”, on fera référence au mythe et non au caractère du héros grec.

La vrai colère étant entière et absolue, le fait de casser le téléphone ou de se rendre compte que l’on a dépassé les bornes n’a pas d’incidence sur l’état qui s’ensuit. C’est un état de retour à la ‘normale’ après un ébranlement émotif puissant, je ne connais pas de non particulier pour celui qui suit la colère.

Comment: Un peu moins diplomatique que votre bonne réponse, mais le deuxième exemple du 2ieme lien contient un autre mot qui décrit bien aussi une telle personne : « lunatique » ! (dans tous les sens du mot)

Comment: "soupe-au-lait" ne signifie pas le calme après la colère, mais le phénomène inverse, comme le lait: une grande période très calme, puis le lait qui bout et se renverse, et ce n'est pas un état transitoire, mais plutôt un trait de caractère. "lunatique", c'est être dans la lune (à côté du sujet, ...), il n'y a pas de notion de colère.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina « Lunatique » signifie bien « à l'humeur changeante » (implicitement : en fonction des phases de la lune) et peut ainsi aussi bien désigner quelqu'un qui passe fréquemment du calme à la colère (et non pas quelqu'un qui est tout le temps rêveur ou « dans la lune »). Mais, comme soupe-au-lait, c'est effectivement plus un trait de caractère qu'un état (et j'ai voté pour votre réponse qui me semble être la bonne !)

Comment: @Relaxed tout à fait d'accord sur l'humeur changeante, mais ça peut être aussi bien triste, enjoué, ...

Comment: IMO, focusing **solely** on the man’s **state** after having calmed down following his outburst ignores an important part of the scenario/question (**il a cassé son téléphone pour satisfaire**); one that involves (& therefore requires addressing) his **character**. CALLING/NAMING him (Comment **appelle**-t-on cet homme?) “short/quick-tempered”(soupe au lait) certainly nails this characteristic perfectly, but it ALSO nails the subsequent quick return to a **calm state**. If anything, “soupe au lait” is too polite: l'd call him dangerously “lunatique.”(in every sense of the word=insane)@Relaxed

Comment: @PapaPoule J'ai répondu à votre commentaire en complétant ma réponse.

Comment: @PapaPoule C'est possible, après tout la question est assez sibylline et la personne qui l'a posée ne maitrise peut-être pas parfaitement le français. Mais si on voulait un trait de caractère, on dirait plutôt qu'il est susceptible de faire ça régulièrement ou que cet épisode n'est qu'un exemple.